# Looking to pass a map in terraform

Tags: module, terraform, terraform0.12+, terragrunt

i have a local yaml file.

```
  - owner: "terraform-service-account"
    principal: "sa-1234"
    resources:
      - resource_name: "be_serivicing"
        resource_type: "TOPIC"
        operation: "WRITE"
      - resource_name: "cjiscool"
        resource_type: "TOPIC"
        operation: "READ"
  - owner: "terraform-service-account-write"
    principal: "sa-948534"
    resources:
      - resource_name: "cjiscoolgroup"
        resource_type: "GROUP"
        operation: "READ"
```

Im looking to pass the values **resource_name**, **resource_type**, **principal** and **operation** to a module.

From my code I have an output

```
output "principals_resources" {


value = {for acl in local.acls : acl.owner => acl.resources}

}
```

which gives me output

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + principals_resources = {
      + terraform-service-account       = [
          + {
              + operation     = "WRITE"
              + resource_name = "be_serivicing"
              + resource_type = "TOPIC"
            },
          + {
              + operation     = "READ"
              + resource_name = "cjiscool"
              + resource_type = "TOPIC"
            },
        ]
      + terraform-service-account-write = [
          + {
              + operation     = "READ"
              + resource_name = "cjiscoolgroup"
              + resource_type = "GROUP"
            },
        ]
    }
```

When I add the for_each in the module initially Im getting two or more values inside the tuple which should be intended from the output.

```
module "acls" {
  source = "../acls"

for_each = {for acl in local.acls : acl.owner => acl.resources}

  resource_type = each.value.resource_type
  resource_name = each.value.resource_name
  principal     = each.value.principal
  operation     = each.value.operation

}
```

How can I pass each **resource_name**, **resource_type**, **operation** and **principal** to a module?

I have tried to output the first map values to another output that would be inputted into my module.  Sorry if this question is confusing, Im new to terraform and need help

**EDIT:** Here is the module. its creating a confluent topic

```
resource "confluent_kafka_acl" "topic_write" {

  count = var.resource_type == "TOPIC" && var.operation == "WRITE" ? 1 : 0

  resource_type = "TOPIC"
  resource_name = var.resource_name
  pattern_type  = "LITERAL"
  principal     = "User:${var.principal}"
  host          = "*"
  operation     = "WRITE"
  permission    = "ALLOW"

}
```

& here is the error Im getting.

```
│   on main.tf line 12, in module "acls":
│   12:   resource_type = each.value.resource_type
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is tuple with 2 elements
│ 
│ This value does not have any attributes.
```

Comment: How did it go? Is is still unclear what you can do?

Comment: Everything is working now. Needed to flatten the original map to loop over the resources in the yaml file

Answer (score 1):

You have to **flatten** you `acls`:

```
locals {   
    acls_flat = merge([
        for owner, values in local.acls: {
            for resource in values.resources: 
               "${owner}-${resource.resource_name}" => {
                   "${owner}" = owner
                   principal = values.principal
                  "resource" = resource
               }   
        }
    ]...)
}
```

then

```
module "acls" {
  source = "../acls"

  for_each = local.acls_flat

  resource_type = each.value.resource.resource_type
  resource_name = each.value.resource.resource_name
  principal     = each.value.principal
  operation     = each.value.operation

}
```